# Dataframe aggregation using Databricks UDF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have a spark data frame where the field_values column might contain a single value OR a list of values. The requirement is to return a sum of field_values if the value of field_values >0.

```
| field_id | field_values    | year | accountNo|
|----------|-----------------|----  |----------|
|pttt.12   |1000.0,34.0,56.0 | 2022 | 1234     |
|--------  |---------------- |------|----------|
|ctty.45   | 5000.0          | 2023 | 4567     |
```

This table can have millions of records, and also the criteria might vary depending on the requirement, like

Aggregator could be Min, Max, Sum

The operator could be lt, gt, eq, etc.

1. sum of value greater than 0 == SUM(field_values, 'gt', 0)
2. MAX value greater than 0 == MAX(field_values, 'gt',0)

and so on.
I'm wondering if the above requirement can be implemented without using UDF.

If not, I'd appreciate it if you could show how to implement it using UDF.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: is the type array of decimal or string for field_values?  If you convert it to an array you can use standard in-built functions: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/sql/index.html#split

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the **Spark SQL** functions and expressions. Here is the corrected code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col, expr

data = [
    ("pttt.12", "1000.0,34.0,56.0", 2022, 1234),
    ("ctty.45", "5000.0", 2023, 4567)
]

sample_data = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["field_id", "field_values", "year", "accountNo"])
sample_data = sample_data.withColumn("field_values", expr("split(field_values, ',')"))
sample_data = sample_data.select("field_id", explode("field_values").alias("field_value"), "year", "accountNo")
sample_data = sample_data.withColumn("field_value", col("field_value").cast("float"))
filtered_data = sample_data.filter(col("field_value") > 0)

final_result = filtered_data.groupBy("year", "accountNo") \
    .agg({"field_value": "sum", "field_value": "max"})
final_result.show()
```

```
+----+---------+----------------+
|year|accountNo|max(field_value)|
+----+---------+----------------+
|2022|     1234|          1000.0|
|2023|     4567|          5000.0|
+----+---------+----------------+
```

In the above code, the **field_values** column is split by commas using the `split` function from the `expr` function of `pyspark.sql.functions`. This converts the comma-separated string into an array of strings.

The `explode` function is used to split each array element into a separate row.

The **field_value** column is `cast` to float using the `cast` function to make it as an **INT** datatype. Then, records where **field_value** is greater than 0 are filtered out.

The data is grouped by **year** and *accountNo*, and two aggregations are performed:

- `Sum` of field_value for each group
- `Max`imum value of field_value for each group